How to cope without a working environment?
I’ve been the solo-developer/engineer in a SaaS startup (and a co-founder) for the past 3 years. This is the case since I graduated and thus I don’t have any "normal" work-experience, I pretty much don’t even know what a working environment is supposed to be, let alone a healthy one.
The startup is growing (painfully) slowly... but growing. It’s still not making any money for us (we're doing with no financing, 3'rd world issues) so I have to switch to some freelance work every now and then to fill the gap, but it’s more or less the same routine of working alone and just communicating on the business needs, it just pays more.
Though it takes quite a toll on my schedule for the startup and I can’t seem to find a middle ground between putting company hours and working for my own sake on the side.
The startup does have growth potential, it’s just that the team is too small, unavailable and severely lacks the experience to do it at the right pace. The product on its own is quite complex, and it should probably not be in the hands of a single junior developper.
Now my issue is that I’ve got really tired of just hacking code and monkeying around on my own from my room, I feel like I’ve trapped myself and missed on a lot of self-development and career-growth, I’ve never gotten any mentorship or worked with anyone else in the technical side, let alone someone with more experience than I.
My soft-skills are probably severely atrophied at this point, and I feel that I’ve stopped learning and picking up new skills, stagnated, and never really specialized in anything.
My productivity has been abysmal the last 6-8 months, I tried taking a month-long vacation (for the first time in many years), yet at the moment I'm just staring at the same piece of code for the past 6 days or so, even running away from switching to my code editor’s window…
I'm deep into the sunk-cost fallacy vis-à-vis this startup to simply walk away from it, and doing so is undoubtedly going to kill the company since there was never anyone else on the tech-side.
I understand that this StackExchange is about the workplace, but my question is ironically on how to have a career, thrive, and evolve without a workplace?
I keep telling myself that I should just stop working at home and move things outside, but we’re a remote team with no offices, and coworking-spaces are really not a thing over here.

What do you think working at home is the major issue here? It sounds like the problem is motivation, not location.

@keshlam I was just thinking it sounded like a troll post to start an argument with the tag line "remote work is bad for us".

Remote work is bad for some folks, and may be bad for them. But that does not seem to be the actual root of the problem being described. If they need supervision, or fewer distractions, or higher bandwidth collaboration, moving into an office may help. If they need basic education, or motivation, or interest in the project, or project planning, or career planning, it may not. This is an X/Y question, jumping to a specific proposed fix rather than stepping back and trying to determine what actually needs to be fixed.

Can you find another job elsewhere ?

Assuming that this isn't a trolling question -
Remote work has little or nothing to do with it.
You are describing someone that is a combination of burnt out and over their head.
Have you and your team considered getting an additional equity partner that is a more senior developer? Ideally, someone that each of you would give some percentage. This person's skillset should be in the areas that your are the least comfortable / productive.
If you aren't comfortable with this, then consider improving your project management skills.
The reason that I suggest that this isn't a remote work issue is because of how you describe not having a clear path forward in:

The Project
Your Career
The Business
Your Comfort

Each of these is in an area that you aren't quite ready to handle by yourself. This isn't a ding. Being in business is more than writing code and where some startups mess up. It is having a clear business plan, a definition of success that you can track via measureable milestones at bare minimum.
Lack of knowing what the priorities are and the milestones to deliver them will cause some of the same symptoms that you're describing.
You haven't said that you can't do the work. You've said that you don't know what work to do next. That is want the team is for. I am not going to going into sprints, etc. because you're talking about not being sure what to do.
That is project management with a good dose of communication between the startup team to fix it.
Good luck. Keep us posted.
UPDATE:
@Sascha and @Kilisi have valid points. The questions back to the OP are:

if they are expecting to use this business / project as fulfil their their social needs? If they are, that is an interesting point of discussion. For example, at my company we try to ensure everyone enjoys (at least not hate) what they do and who they work with. But it isn't expected to be their social life. For the OP is it an extrapolation that a slow moving / no moving project is covering up lack of a social life?
is the problem more than lack of project management? Is there no vision and a complete lack of leadership? Project management is easily fixed. Lack of leadership is much harder. Lack of vision isn't fixable IMHO.

Does the OP see these two points as the root cause?

This isn't a business, it's a hobby that you're no longer enjoying. It might be time to find a new hobby and write this off to experience.
3 years making zero is too long. This is a major fail from the marketing side. Many businesses and especially startups rely on their marketing people to source funding etc,. If it's not happening, then the technical people need to either leave or change their marketing monkeys.
If I saw potential, I'd quit, let it all fall apart. Then maybe build it quietly on my own and restart when I have an actual working and lucrative product to sell.

2 things:

You say that this is an SaaS company and you are the sole developer with a co-founder. What is Mr. Big Idea doing to make your shared vision a reality?

They aren't getting you investment money/helping you the developer build the thing. If this took a lot longer/ended up being more complex then you both thought it would, they don't seem to understand the problem space.
'Big Ideas' are cheap and seldom worth the paper they were written on. The details is where the money is at.
You don't owe it to Mr. Big Idea to keep this company going.

90% of startups fail in the first 5 years, 95% fail within 10 years.

This isn't working, it isn't good for your personnel development/future... You don't have the technical skill set/ years of experience at this moment to make this SaaS. There is no shame in that.
It is going to be harder for you in many ways to find a job to pay the bills/develop the skills you need to make your vision a reality, and the longer you wait, the harder its going to be. Your freelance work should help with this.
I honestly recommend that you get an in person job working with more senior engineers, if you can find one. Yes I know that remote work is all the rag, but it is terrible for junior engineers because you don't get to learn via osmosis from the senior engineers.

Every human strives to be part of a social collective. A member of a social cohort. A group that shares the same properties. To identify, to mingle and to receive and give acknowledgment.
You are experiencing social deprivation. You lack appreciation, comfort, identity, reason and motivation.
You have to start socialising. Join a club, start mingling, be a relied part of a community.
Be someone's reason to be happy.

Perhaps the definition of work environment is a tricky one for you. If you have the skills, insight and vision for the company but lack the social environment that you seek then perhaps it is wise to visit professional congresses around your software product niche. I can hardly imagine the SaaS environment lacks any decent support groups where you can sharpen the saw by mingling with like-minded folks. Do beware of false shepherds though. When you're in trouble, suddenly everyone seems to be a trusted advisor. Ask focused and specific questions if you are serious about personal and business development.
Remember also that some of us are more extrinsically motivated, and as opposed to intrinsic motivation this just requires a different approach since there is no good or bad. I see us as vocal internet humans quite ready to point fingers and trying to offer help like that. But human psychology is a tricky topic and there are well-paid professional career coaches for a very damn good reason.
The sunken cost-fallacy sounds rational, but it is not. Some products simply don't take off regardless of effort or quality and to kill your darlings is part of strategic business decisions.

Seems a bit fluffy to me.
